# How to handle both selected index change of combobox column and keypress event of text box column in datagridviw editingcontrolshowing event?

Tags: vb.net

I have a datagridview in winform, in which four columns exists.Out of which 1 comboxcolumn and other three textboxcolumn. I have handeled combobox selected index change properly and it working fine. I handle this on Datagridview_editigControlShowing() event. Now i want to handle other three textboxes keyprees event so user can only enter numeric value. Now i searched on net there are some solution, but when i add another handler in editingControlShowing() method at run time when i click on combobox, it shows error.But when i remove the addHandler for textbox its worked fine.

My Code is look like

Private Sub dgvPurchase_EditingControlShowing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs) Handles dgvPurchase.EditingControlShowing

```
    Dim editComboBox As ComboBox = TryCast(e.Control, ComboBox)
    If Not editComboBox Is Nothing Then
        AddHandler editComboBox.SelectedIndexChanged, AddressOf editComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged
    End If
    'RemoveHandler dgvPurchase.EditingControlShowing, AddressOf dgvPurchase_EditingControlShowing

End Sub
```

Now is there any way to handle both of these if so please provide me the solution